# @angular/cli not working after installation

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I have installed the @angular/cli on my MacBook machine. Node server version is v6.9.5 and the npm version is 3.10.10. I have ran the following command to install the @angular/cli.

> sudo npm install -g @angular-cli

When I run the ng help command or any command for ng. It shows me the following error

> Parsing .angular-cli.json failed. Please make sure your .angular-cli.json 
>   is valid JSON.
>   Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 22

```
InvalidConfigError: Parsing .angular-cli.json failed. Please make sure your 
.angular-cli.json is valid JSON. 
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 22
   at InvalidConfigError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:10:9)
   at Function.fromConfigPath (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config/config.js:77:19)
   at Function.fromProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/config.js:96:46)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:7:35)
   at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
   at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
   at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
```

I also uninstalled and @angualr/cli and clear the cache then reinstalled @angualr/cli. I run the following command.

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular-cli 
npm cache clean sudo 
npm install -g @angular-cli
```

Still the same issue is appearing.

Comment: @angular-cli is now depreciated try installing `@angular/cli@latest`

Comment: I installed the @angular/cli package. Before that I uninstalled the previous package and cleared the cache.Still the same error message.

Answer (score 4):

The package is called `@angular/cli`, so do `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Comment: I installed the @angular/cli package. Before that I uninstalled the previous package and cleared the cache. Still the same error message.

Comment: The format of `angular-cli.json` has changed couple of times. Maybe you still have an old version. Can you post your JSON somewhere with a link so we can have a look what might be wrong with it?

Comment: there is no file with this name on this path.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/. 
could you please tell me the exact path of this file?

Comment: It should be in the root of your project (same location as package.json).

Comment: After installation, when I run the 
ng new project-name. Then the error occurs. How can be file exist in the root of the project?

Answer (score 1):

`@angular-cli` is the previous version. Now you need to

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

to work with `@angular/cli` version

Comment: I installed the @angular/cli package. Before that I uninstalled the previous package and cleared the cache.Still the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

The package you mentioned is not valid. For fresh installation use `npm install -g @angular/cli`.
Check here for more details https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation

---

Also If you are upgrading follow this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

---

If you upgrading from a beta/RC version follow this https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update

---

`angular-cli` uses angular.cli.json.
whereas `@angular/cli` uses .angular.cli.json

Answer (score 0):

i also face same issue, so i tried this method given below.

Clean uninstall of angular-cli, like npm uninstall -g angular-cli
Clone this angular-cli repo,
Go to the angular-cli repo folder, and run npm link,
Go to my project folder
Run npm link angular-cli
Now to run ng command, I use ./node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng from my project folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to install @angular/cli globally to use it anywhere.To install it globally use cmd 'npm i -g @angular/cli',where -g means globally.Even update your angular version to latest.I think the error is because in older versions of angular,the angular.json file name used to be saved differently and its name is differently saved in newer or latest versions,so after installation it might not be able to read your angular.json file.